# Serial Program working better than Parallel Program

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, parallel-processing

I am trying to make a comparison between serial and parallel processing in Image processing.
But for some strange reason, my parallel program is running much slower than the serial program.
Can anyone tell me what might be the problem ?

Parallel Code:
I have divided each task as a separate function for each thread.

```
def task2():
global t_end
print("Task 2 started...")

filter=[1/9,1/9,1/9,1/9,1/9,1/9,1/9,1/9,1/9]
for i in range(1, height - 2):
    for j in range(1, width - 2):
        # print i,j,img[i][j]
        ay = img[i - 1][j - 1] * float(filter[0])
        by = img[i][j - 1] * float(filter[1])
        cy = img[i + 1][j - 1] * float(filter[2])
        dy = img[i - 1][j] * float(filter[3])
        ey = img[i][j] * float(filter[4])
        fy = img[i + 1][j] * float(filter[5])
        gy = img[i - 1][j + 1] * float(filter[6])
        hy = img[i][j + 1] * float(filter[7])
        iy = img[i + 1][j + 1] * float(filter[8])

        Gy = ay + by + cy + dy + ey + fy + gy + hy + iy
        img_op2[i][j] = Gy
print("Active Threads :", threading.activeCount())
cv2.imshow('Blurred op', img_op2)
temp_time = time.time()
if (temp_time > t_end):
    t_end = temp_time
```

And I have implemented the threads in this way :

```
t1=threading.Thread(target=task1)
t2=threading.Thread(target=task2)
t3=threading.Thread(target=task3)
t4=threading.Thread(target=task4)

t_start=time.time()
t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
t4.start()
```

My parallel code is working way slower than the serial code for some reason. Any suggestion would be appriciated.

Comment: You are executing everything in Python threads. Due to GIL, standard Python can only run one thread at a time.

Comment: Use the multiprocessing module instead of thread.

Comment: Is this tagged `opencv` because you'd like to take advantage of OpenCV functionality to improve performance, or simply because you happen to `imshow` the result? In the first case, if you want performance, I'd suggest to use `cv2.filter2D` instead of those loops. In the other case, I'd suggest removing the tag, since it's irrelevant to the problem of parallelizing pure Python algorithm.